# Can my Q Bag Tag be used by another traveller?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, check-in, qantas

I have multiple [Q Bag Tags](http://www.qantas.com/travel/airlines/q-bag-tag/global/en) from my airline Qantas.

If I lend one to a friend, are they able to use it?

It's unclear whether the tag is permanently associated with my frequent flyer number, or if it is associated with a frequent flyer number only upon each check-in.

I have tried calling the support line (13 11 31), but the wait is usually too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can according to [Australian Business Traveller](http://www.ausbt.com.au/tip-qantas-wireless-bag-tags-can-be-used-by-anyone):

> In response to a series of Australian Business Traveller enquiries,
>   Qantas today confirmed that the electronic tags are not linked to any
>   one traveller's frequent flyer profile, but rather, are linked to a
>   specific check-in.

...

> At the bag drop, the Q Bag Tag is synchronised with the boarding pass
>   or Qantas card and flight details that are scanned at the bag drop.
>   The flight details are then recorded in the Q Bag Tag for that flight.
>   The Q Bag Tag does not store any personal information (except the
>   original frequent flyer number the tag was allocated to, so we can
>   find the owner of the tag if it were lost).

Answer (score 1):

The Q Bag Tag is basically an rfid chip embedded device, that when you check your bag, the id is read and then programmed into the system so the bag can be routed / traced.  So in theory it shouldn't matter which Q-Tag you use, as it would be read every time you check in.

But I am not sure if Qantas programs additional data onto the chip such as your frequent flyer number or name or has already stored the rfid numbers in your FF profile or simply connects the rfid id to your account each time you check in.

You could loan the device to your friend, let them try it on a flight.  Worse case scenario at check in the system will reject the Q Tag because it doesn't match the name on the booking and print out an old fashion "temporary" tag.

Comment: In the absence of any advice from Qantas on it, I agree I'll just need to arrive with enough time to try it and see. I'm still looking for confirmation beforehand, though, as it's a much quicker check-in when the printed tag isn't required.